# Get text area value by its name in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get value of text area using its name in pure javascript

```
<textarea cols="70" rows="3" name="tempText">This is a Textarea</textarea>
```

I tried with this but its not working showing error
[image: Error]

```
document.getElementByName("tempText").value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. Here are two of the simplest ones

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea[name="tempText"]');
console.log(textarea.value);
```

OR

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByName('tempText')[0];
console.log(textarea.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Typo: It should be `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName`

`getElementsByName` Returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the (X)HTML document. so you need to specify index of element you want to access. In your case use 0 to get the value. [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByName("tempText")[0].value);
```

```html
<textarea cols="70" rows="3" name="tempText">This is a Textarea</textarea>
```

Comment: The said method doesn't return an array, please consult the manual.

Comment: @Teemu: yes. It doesn;t return an Array. But it is still and array like object which can be accessed using bracket notation. This is a correct way to do it.

Comment: Yep, but it's important to make clear, that the returned object is not an array. Though in modern browsers NodeList has `forEach` method, other array methods like pop, sort etc. are not included.

Comment: i updated my answer with @Teemu suggestion . thanks teemu and AdityaParab

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByName("tempText")[0].value
```

if you're sure that you've only one element (textarea) with that name.

Answer (score 0):

It's `getElementsByName` .
Here you noticed the plural `getElements`. It returns an array-like NodeList of elements with that name attribute.

> The `getElementsByName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as a `NodeList object`.
>
> The `NodeList` object represents a collection of nodes. Although `NodeList` is not an Array, it is possible to iterate on it using `forEach()`. The index starts at 0.

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName("tempText")[0].value);
```